# When should I use a condensed font?

Tags: typography, font-size, white-space

*I was advised to post [this question from User Experience (UX)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76605/when-should-i-use-a-condensed-font) to this site instead.*

---

Assuming I always have enough space to write what I need to write, and I never get into a position like https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/what-is-the-best-font-for-extremely-limited-space-i-e-will-fit-the-most-readab, when should I use a condensed font?  Is it ever appropriate, or does it just make the UI [feel cramped](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/20/condensed-fonts-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/)?

The reason I am asking this is because I have six items on the screen at once:

[image]
Would this be an appropriate time for a condensed font?  I can fit all the wanted text with a wider font, but there is less space between sections with this wider font.  However, the condensed font of course makes the text look more cramped.

Is this a case where a condensed font would be appropriate?  If not, when would be an appropriate time to use it?

Comment: One advantage of a condensed font would be that you can make it larger and still have enough white space between the sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to most any "when should I use typestyle X" is: when it looks appropriate.

That said, note that condensed faces are typically considered display faces. They're not necessarily meant for use as a text face, but rather for things like headers and headlines. Newspapers especially like them because you can fit a lot more into a headline with a condensed face--leaving space elsewhere for more ads.

Therefore, as a general rule of thumb, use condensed faces in large sizes as you see fit. Beware of potentially reducing legibility when used at small sizes--especially in lower resolution settings, like a desktop screen.